# How to validate if sum of values are equal in Validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vuejs2

I have this accounting project where I need to validate if debit and credit are equal before saving to the database.

e.g

```
accounts: [
    {

        id: 1,
        account_id: 1,
        debit:  1000
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        account_id: 5,
        credit: 1500
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        account_id: 8,
        debit: 500
    }
]
```

By the way I am using axios and lodash.

```
axios.post('/api/journals', {

    accounts : map(this.accounts, function(account) {

        account_id: account.account_id,
        debit: account.debit,
        credit: account.credit
    })
}
```

Can anyone suggest how to implement this validation rule.

Comment: Do you want to enforce this rule across all account IDs? It seems like the debit and credit amounts belong to different accounts: how should they be coalesced?

Comment: @Terry. Yes I think. I have a posting table which is a pivot table (account_journal). The first step would be creation of the journal then attaching it to the posting table.

Answer (score 0):

The validation rule has nothing to do with Laravel or VueJS. All you need is to use lodash to iterate through your `accounts` array, sum the debit and credit numbers separately, and compare them thereafter:

```
var debitSum = _.reduce(data.accounts, function(sum, account) {
  return (account.debit || 0) + sum;
}, 0);

var creditSum = _.reduce(data.accounts, function(sum, account) {
  return (account.credit || 0) + sum;
}, 0);

console.log('Debit: ' + debitSum + '; Credit: ' + creditSum);

if (debitSum !== creditSum) {
    // Debit and credit sums do not match
} else {
    // Debit and credit sums match
}
```

The code above uses the [`_.reduce()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#reduce) method to calculate the sum of debit/credit amounts. Since `debit` and `credit` keys are not guanranteed to be present all the time, we use the `||` operator to assign a value of 0 when it is falsy (e.g. `undefined`, `null`, `0`, empty string, etc.)

Here's a proof-of-concept example:

```js
var data = { accounts: [{
    id: 1,
    account_id: 1,
    debit: 1000
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    account_id: 5,
    credit: 1500
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    account_id: 8,
    debit: 500
  }
]};

var debitSum = _.reduce(data.accounts, function(sum, account) {
  return (account.debit || 0) + sum;
}, 0);

var creditSum = _.reduce(data.accounts, function(sum, account) {
  return (account.credit || 0) + sum;
}, 0);

console.log('Debit: ' + debitSum + '; Credit: ' + creditSum);

if (debitSum !== creditSum) {
  console.log('Debit and credit are not equal!');
} else {
  console.log('All ok');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I got your point. However I am using an API for this project. That is why I want to implement the validation on the server side. Not on the client. That's why I thought I could achieve this through custom validation for laravel.